# Change color of Bootstrap background navbar

Tags: css, colors, navigation, navbar

I'm curious how to change the color of the navbar. I'm using bootstrap business casual.

Here's the picture of the navbar whose color I want to change.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details and some code.

Comment: did you mean HTML code or the CSS? also how to upload? sry im new :( @StuartWagner

Comment: Well, you didn't explain what it is you want to change. What exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the background color in the file business-casual.css at line 163.

```
.navbar-default {
    border: none;
    background: #fff; <-- white
    background: rgba(255, 129, 117, 0.9); <-- kind of red with 90% transparancy
}
```

You probably also want to change the color of the navbar text. This you can find in bootstrap.min.css at line 4861.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #777; <-- grey
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. The box below on business casual is on that CSS also? Sry im really new to the programming. Im still learning on CSS and html

Comment: This white box
http://s4.postimg.org/4l28lsw9p/asdf.png

If i want to change the color / width / height? can i ? i saw the class is "col-lg-12". When i search on CSS, didn't found any "color" on those.

Comment: Look into an css inspector like https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console it has tools like these html css selction stuff https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles#inspecting-elements